# How to limit WooCommerce Product title length for every title separately?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the WooCommerce blog page with thumbnails I am basically having products where I would like to cut off the title after 3 words but others after 5 words, and so on. I have added this snippet to my functions.php file:

```
function short_woocommerce_product_titles_words( $title, $id ) {
  if ( ( is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category() ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
    $title_words = explode(" ", $title);
    if ( count($title_words) > 5 ) { // Kicks in if the product title is longer than 5 words
      // Shortens the title to 5 words and adds ellipsis at the end
      return implode(" ", array_slice($title_words, 0, 5)) . '...';
    } else {
      return $title; // If the title isn't longer than 5 words, it will be returned in its full length without the ellipsis
    }
  } else {
    return $title;
  }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'short_woocommerce_product_titles_words', 10, 2 );
```

Which works totally fine limiting my titles to a max of 5 words but I don't want that for each and every title. Is there a way to have a separate argument on top of the above code to limit certain titles without affecting the others? I assume it would be a bit tedious but there's not a lot of new items added to the shop (it's a bookshop) so it would be a one time thing anyways.

Thanks!

Comment: if its just one time thing, than in your if statement with count>5 just compare string you need with $title and do with it what you want

Comment: That applies it to all titles (except the is_* checks), if you only want specific truncating just create a function which is not a filter and wrap your titles with it.

Comment: Or create a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), it is wordpress after all.

Answer (score 0):

In what other case do you want to slice only 3 words for example ?

If this is because some words are very long you can count all the letters on the title and set the right number of words according to this:

```
$letters_count = strlen($title);
$title_words = explode(" ", $title);

if($letters_count >= 20) {
   $title = implode(" ", array_slice($title_words, 0, 5)) . '...';
}elseif($letters_count >= 30) {
   $title = implode(" ", array_slice($title_words, 0, 3)) . '...';
}

return $title
```

EDIT:

Or if you want to have control over this, you can add a metabox with a checkbox inside that allow you to check if you want the product to have a shorter title.

- Add a metabox with `"trim_title"` post meta for example that return **true** or **false** : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336
- And in front check it with: `$trim_this_title = get_post_meta($id, 'trim_title', true);`. If `$trim_this_title` is **true** so do your code, else just return the normal `$title`

Comment: Would this work for separate titles? I'm not that handy in writing php I'm afraid.

For example, one title looks fine having it sliced after 3 words, but the second one is cut short and I'd rather have it sliced after 5 words while a third title would have to be sliced after 4.